# :hover stops after hovering autocomplete field

Tags: jquery, html, css, autocomplete

I never was a big fan of javascript dropdowns, so when I can style a dropdown using CSS I will. But now Im running into a small problem.

I have a login button, and a small login form module, which is a sibling of the button. When I hover over the button, the login form shows up directly under it (By setting `display:block` on his brother) and you can go to the form where the hover over the form takes over so the form module doesnt disappear again.

It's all pretty easy:

```
#home-login-button:hover + #login, #login:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

[A JSFiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/6NeTG/)

The problem I have is that when I type in a letter, my browser wants to autocomplete. If I for example type "h" it drops down "Hans Wassink". But when I hover that autocomplete box the whole thing pops like a bubble. Im no longer hovering the login module so it disappears. Very Annoying. Is there anything I can do? I know I can set autocomplete to 'off' but I want my users to have that option.

I noticed it also happens when I use the same solution but with jQuery.

EDIT: To complete the question. Im on FF28 / Windows. But My colleagues here have it too on other versions of FF and on IE (The receptionist, the rest has real browsers :) ).

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome Version 34.0.1847.131 m and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Which browser? Working for me in chrome, using the same autocomplete.

Comment: its working fine on chrome, must be a problem with your browser.

Comment: Im using FF28 on Windows, Ill edit my post. But it happens in other versions of FF and on IE too.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Ok guys, we established that it's working in Chrome :D

Comment: I see the problem on Chrome Version 80.0.3987.163 (Official Build) (64-bit). In Chrome, if I select from dropdown quickly before hover disappears, then all is good. The hover remains. If I hover on a select option without selecting it, then the whole hover disappears. Firefox is worse: hover always disappears.

Comment: It's Feb 2021 and I confirm it happens on chrome, firefox, edge, all latest version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a Jquery Solution.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="login"> <span>Login</span>

    <div class="login_form">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.login {
    position: relative;
    height:60px;
    width:50px;
    margin:30px;
}
.login > span {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.login_form {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px;
    padding:10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: none;
}
```

JQUERY CODE

```
$('.login').on('mouseover', function () {
    $('.login_form', this).show();
}).on('mouseout', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('input')) {
        $('.login_form', this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Answer is Updated. Actually ");" was missing is Jquery Code. Now Updated Code Run Fine.

Comment: Hey there, using this jquery it works. But I'm still looking for a just CSS solution

Comment: That autocomplete list is listed by browser. It is not Possible with CSS.

Comment: I kinda feel it's buggy, im gonna nag at Mozilla ;), thanks anyways!

Comment: @HansWassink did you found a css solution ? Couldn't find a fix for that problem and it looks like it's present on more Browser. If you found a solution please share ;D.

Comment: @delato468 Unfortunately not :(

Comment: @HansWassink oh well then the only way maybe is to disable the autofill from browser oO. Im prefer to use the login into the navigation.

Comment: @HansWassink Well i was searching now for a while and tried things like input:-webkit-autofill:hover .navdropdown{ visibility:1; display:block;} ... nothing working. Onliest thing working is to set it directly to input:-webkit-autofill. Then the autofill won't disappear together with the dropdown, but' it's not optimal :( and there are a lot other browsers wich need this set up. Don't understand why this question is as low upvoted. Im using now the jquery code above, but i recommend to use addClass and removeClass instead of show and hide.

Comment: @delato468 Thanks for your extra input, especially after . I also agree with your `addClass` and `removeClass` comment. That is way better in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` didn't work for us, these events were also triggered when we hovered over the suggestion list. Instead we listened for focus/blur on the input element. Downside is that once you start entering something in the field the user **has** to click outside the dropdown, regardless of if he used the autocomplete or not.

```
 <div class="login"> <span>Login</span>
    <div class="login_form">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

With this jquery code:

```
$('.login input').on('focus', function () {
    $('.login_form').addClass("open");
}).on('blur', function () {
    $(".login_form").removeClass("open");
});
```

and of course this css:

```
.open {display: block}
```